# Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working in Microsoft Visual Studio to create my RDL's. I have a sub report which refuses to run when we put it up on SSRS. This report runs fine inside of Visual studio in preview mode even when pointed at a copy of the prod database (still takes 30 min to run but it completes). The report only returns 1 row with counts of a large amount of data for a summary.

The full error text is:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   o   Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
>   A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded. Operation cancelled by user.

This report used to work but the query was not correctly pulling the information. I had to change the query and expand what it was pulling from the database. Is there any way this could be caused by not enough memory being given to SSRS? We are using SSRS 2008 r2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem was solved by putting in the recommended indexes provided by SQL Query Analyzer. After the indexes were created the query ran in ~4 min no problems.